# Reference XSLT-file using a project relative way (instead of an absolute path)

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

The file at *xsltFileName* is in my project *WebSite2* (at the root-level of the project). I currently use an absolute path to get the XSLT file name:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
String xsltFileName = "file:///C:\\Documents and Settings\\kentl\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2005\\WebSites\\WebSite2\\page.xsl";
xslt.Load(xsltFileName);
```

I would like to have a solution without an absolute path. What would be the cleanest way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
String xsltFileName = Server.MapPath("~/page.xsl");
xslt.Load(xsltFileName);
```

Or, if you are not inside a Web Form (i.e., a Business Object):

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
String xsltFileName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/page.xsl");
xslt.Load(xsltFileName);
```